# XHTML and viewport tag

Tags: jsf, jquery-mobile, xhtml, viewport

Viewport tag is recommended (as follows), for optimised zoom levels in mobile browsers:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The above idea is mentioned [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

I use jQuery Mobile and JSF in my project, and thus using XHTML pages.

XHTML does not allow viewport tag be used as above, instead it demands a closing tag as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

But if used with closing tag, zoom level is not as expected in iPhone.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that it's caused by the self-closing tag? Isn't that more an iPhone bug? Have you tried using `<meta ...></meta>` instead? Or perhaps inserting a space before `/>`? Do you have any authoritative references proving this iPhone problem (I can't seem to find any in Google so far now and I don't have an iPhone to play around with)? You can solve it with a custom component+renderer, but I find that a clumsy solution which should be for last resort only.

Comment: Using closing tag in different ways does not seem to be solving this issue. This (or related) issue is mentioned here:http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html